# Invalid literal because symbol appears when reading a csv file

Tags: csv, ide

When I am using replit I can remove the little symbol that appears when I drag and drop in a csv file so my main.py can read it, otherwise I get invalid literal base 10 issue. I am trying to run this on local machine with sublime text and getting same error now as it is reading the file from the directory, so I assume it is adding this symbol in before reading.... I can click on the csv file in replit and edit, but cannot do this in sublime.

Can someone explain what this is for? HOw can I get it to read the basic comma delimited numbers in the file (It is a game tile map).

```
with open(f'level{level}_data.csv', newline= '') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Saved it is comma delimited csv instead of UTF-8 comma delimited csv. It then imports without the 'question mark in a diamon' symbol. I understand this is an unrecognised special character, but I have nothing apart from integers in my table. Maybe someone could clarify that?...